# loading data into TableView from Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform, tableview

Hi Guys I have created a function which is below which saves items to a tweetData : [PFObject] array

```
 func loadData() {

    //all current data to be displayed, adding data 1 by 1 remove whats there on reloading
    tweetData.removeAll()

    //query database for all tweets, very important that whats in the classname here, is the
    //same name as the class with Parse where these are being stored

    let findTweets:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Tweets")

    findTweets.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            for object:PFObject in objects! {

                self.tweetData.append(object)

            }

            //--very important!!! dont forget to reload table data otherwise you will return no results
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        } else {

            print("nothing to load")

        }

    }

}
```

how can I get this into my tableview to display the data? been struggling and getting a variety of errors. This is my table view cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath  

 indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //use your custom table view cell here which is defined in another class

    let cell:CellTableViewCellController = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellTableViewCellController


  //NEED TO LOAD MY DATA



    return cell

    //-----add load data function to viewDidAppear method


}
```

could anyone help me on this at all?     thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
all sorted just used query.objectforkey


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //use your custom table view cell here which is defined in another class

    let cell:CellTableViewCellController = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellTableViewCellController

    let query = tweetData[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel!.text = query.objectForKey("TweetContent") as? String

    return cell

    //-----add load data function to viewDidAppear method


}
```